# Error mahout in hortonworks

Tags: mahout, hortonworks-data-platform, bigdata

I trying to execute mahout in `hortonworks (ambari 2.2, HDP 2.4)` but I get error "`Error: JAVA_HOME is not set`". Please, help me to manage for this issue and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Set JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk in .bashrc or run 'export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk' in terminal.